# Can javascript handle automatically sending an email based on form content?

Tags: javascript, forms, email, smtp

Can javascript handle automatically sending the contents of a HTML form?

So the goal would be click send and the contents of the form get formatted and sent with out the user needing to send from their personal email client.

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question, care to expand?

Comment: You can't send an email directly from client side javascript. You will need to do this on the server side.

Comment: Thank you for commenting!  I'm sorry for the poor question.  I am new and didn't really know how to phrase the question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send the contents to a service on the back end which sends out an email for them. Of course the origin would be different from their normal email address.

But you can't have JavaScript in a browser send an email directly. The browser doesn't have any capabilities like that and even if it did they would have to restrict it massively to prevent security problems.